# Cancelling a DownloadStringTaskAsync and restart it

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, webclient, cancellation

I'm downloading a string from a webpage using `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync` asynchronously.

About 4 out of 5 times, this completes successfully, but occasionally, it hangs, and I will have to restart the program to "reset" it.

Thus I'm thinking of implementing a time-out that automatically cancels the Task after 5 seconds and restarts it:

```
async void DoTasks()
{
    string output;

    int timeout = 5000;
    WebClient client = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
    Task<string> task = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task)
    {
        output = task.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        client.CancelAsync();
        DoTasks();
    }
}
```

This, however, returns a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: There is no way that this code could cause `NullReferenceException`. Probably it is inside `GetTasks` method. Also, you're not disposing the `WebClient`.

Comment: You need to add the `GetTasks` method to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, GetTasks was supposed to be DoTasks - restarting the method

Comment: Nothing obvious that could cause `NullReferenceException` here. Which line throws the exception?

Comment: You should also post the original code that causes the hang. You're actually asking two unrelated questions.

Comment: The NullReferenceException seems to be caused by code executed after, code which uses "output", so it seems that when DoTasks is being restarted, it doesn't execute properly.

I'm certain that DownloadStringTaskAsync ocasionally causes it to hang and it seems to it sometime fails to connect.

Comment: How do you call `DoTasks`?

Comment: Currently just using `DoTasks()`. Should I use `Task.Run(() => DoTasks())`?

Comment: `DoTasks` should be `async Task` and not `async void`. And then you need to `await DoTasks()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on await/async, i'm still learning myself but maybe you should do something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inline code to test");
            Console.WriteLine(StartTask(true));

            Console.WriteLine("Get actual website to test, write the length of the text only");
            Console.WriteLine(StartTask(false).Length);

            Console.Write("Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string StartTask(bool DoTestInsteadOfGetUrl)
        {
            var task = DoTasks(DoTestInsteadOfGetUrl);
            Task.WaitAny(task);

            return task.Result;
        }

        async static Task<string> DoTasks(bool DoTestInsteadOfGetUrl)
        {
            int timeout = 20;
            int count = 1;
            CancellationTokenSource cts;
            string output;                
            do
            {
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
                if (DoTestInsteadOfGetUrl)
                {
                    output = await Task<string>.Run(() => test(count, cts.Token), cts.Token);
                }
                else
                {
                    WebClient client = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
                    output = await Task<string>.Run(() => client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.google.com"), cts.Token);
                }

                if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("try #" + count++);
                    timeout += DoTestInsteadOfGetUrl ? 100 : 50;
                }
            } while (cts.IsCancellationRequested);

            return output;
        }

        async static Task<string> test(int count, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            int sleep = 400 - (count * 5);
            await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(sleep), ct);

            if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("succeed #" + count);
            }
            return sleep.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. For starters, it doesn't include the OP's `WebClient` call, which you'll need to make inside `DoTasks`. But your `DoTasks` is `void`, and doesn't contain the `async` modifier. This currently won't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I updated my code... hope it is better